# the problem is warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’

Tags: c

I am trying to run a simple C program but I am getting this error:
format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’

```
char *rarity;
scanf("%c",&rarity);
 
for (int i = 0; i < lootItemNum; i++)
{
   
    if (strncmp(items[i]->rarityItem,rarity,10)==0)
    {
        printf("%s %d %d %s %d %f\n", items[i]->nameItem, items[i]->itemLevel, items[i]->value, items[i]->rarityItem, items[i]->durability, items[i]->probability);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with this.

`char *rarity;` deciares a pointer that is uninitialized, it doesn't point to valid memory you can write to.

`scanf("%c",&rarity);` has two problems, the one you're asking about which is passing the address of a pointer where a pointer is expected, and the format string should be `" %c"` so it skips any leading whitespace before scanning the character.

If all of that was fixed you'd still have a problem with `if (strncmp(items[i]->rarityItem,rarity,10)==0)` because `rarity` isn't a string, it's just a character.

You probably want something like:

```
// Declare an array of 11 (10 characters + terminating 0)
// elements and initialize them all to 0.
char rarity[11] = {0};
// Try to read a string of up to 10 characters and store it in rarity.
// You don't need an & when passing an array to scanf
// The array decays to a pointer to the first element of the array
if (scanf("%10s", rarity) != 1)
{
    // The string wasn't converted, handle the error somehow here
}

for (int i = 0; i < lootItemNum; i++)
{
    if (strncmp(items[i]->rarityItem,rarity,10)==0)
    {
        printf("%s %d %d %s %d %f\n", 
            items[i]->nameItem, items[i]->itemLevel, items[i]->value,
            items[i]->rarityItem, items[i]->durability,
            items[i]->probability);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi thankyou, this is really help. But what should I do with //the string wasn't converted, handle the error somehow.

Comment: I can't really answer that for you. You need to decide what is appropriate to do in your program if the input wasn't read. It may never happen, but I felt it was important to show that there could be an error there that you should check for and handle if it does happen.